# I/O error on GET request for Try again; nested exception is java.net.UnknownHostException: Try again

Tags: java, spring-boot, resttemplate

Technologies: Java + Spring boot(2.5.2). I have upgraded my application from Java 8 to Java 11 (OpenJDK).

Previously I received below error so that I used do-while loop to retry until receive success response.

Java 8 - received success response less than 5 attempts

Java 11 - at 10th attempt also I am receiving same error

Error Log:

> I/O error on POST request for "https://<externalurl>": <externalurl>; nested exception is java.net.UnknownHostException: <externalurl>

```
@Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        restTemplate.setErrorHandler(new ResponseErrorHandler());
        SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory();
        requestFactory.setOutputStreaming(false);
        restTemplate.setRequestFactory(requestFactory);
        return restTemplate;
    }
```

Comment: `UnknownHostException` - What it says on the label.  If you know the host exists then your machine (or network) is having DNS resolution issues.  If it's an IP address instead of a hostname your network is having basic connectivity issues, or there's a firewall blocking access to the IP.  Without more details we really can't help.

Comment: We are building a docker image with OpenJDK 11 and Alpine latest version, deploying on Azure Kubernetes Services

Answer (score 0):

Custom docker image with the combination of Alpine v3.11.3 and OpenJDK 11 working for me. There is some issue with DNS resolution in all other versions of Alpine (Latest version v3.15.0 also).

We will face similar issue in Debian OS - retry logic like sending same request again will work